# Get the Date on which a particular page was liked by me using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any way using FB Graph API by which I can find the date on which the particular page was liked by me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

The date/timestamp of when a “like” happened is not available via the API.